# Disabled attribute not working with class attribute on button in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to make a text box disabled used following code, here diasbled is
not working but the class is working. I am using codeigniter.

```
<?php echo form_submit('Submit', 'Search',"class='btnSearch'","disabled='true'");?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement below code.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'name'       => 'Submit',
    'id'         => 'newsletter',
    'value'      => 'Search',
    'class'      => 'btnSearch',
    'disabled'   => 'true',
);
echo form_submit($data);
?>
//Would produce:  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" id="newsletter" class="btnSearch" disabled="true">
```

I hope you problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this.

```
<?php
$attributes = array(
    'class'      => 'btnSearch',
    'disabled'   => 'true',
);
echo form_submit('Submit','Search',$attributes);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use readonly

```
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="btnSearch" readonly="true">
```